# Which DLL will support pan tilt and zoom in c#

Tags: c#-4.0, dll, directshow, directshow.net

Here by i created a windows application in c# by using directshowlib. dll  and dshow.dll.. camera i am using logitech Webcam Pro 9000 ..it does not support pan tilt and zoom ..so pl hereby help me which dll mostly supports all cam..

help me thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

[VisioForge Video Capture SDK .Net](http://www.visioforge.com/video-capture-sdk-net2.html)

Or using [IAMCameraControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd389145%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in your code.

P.S. Not all cameras support this interface fully, all DirectShow software support is using IAMCameraControl interface (usually) or specific vendor interfaces (sometimes).

Comment: i am using IAMCAMERACONTROL interface in directshow library.it doesn't support pan tilt and zoom ..better shall i go with direct x sdk 9.0 whether its supports?

Comment: no, result will be the same. i think your camera just not supported it, or have a private interface.

Comment: When i am using logitech webcam (default software) it works perfectly with all feature (pan,tilt,zoom and face detection)..Then which one shall i prefer Roman ....Pl help me

Comment: Whether demo version of visioforge will support pan tilt and zoom functionality? i tried with demo version of visioforge samples  the pan zoom and tilt functionality is disabled ..can u give me some suggestions regarding this